# Keeping track of refreshes in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am curious to know if there is a way to tell if a report has been printed or ran. For example, the user enters in a inspectionnumber and hits apply and then clicks print and then prints the report. Can i know if the report has been printed? is there a way to use local variables to track that, some sort of loop?

Comment: Are you asking from within Crystal Reports, or are you wondering if it can be done programmatically?

Comment: @Dusty Yes i am in Crystal Reports 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tested this, but here's a theory you can try.

In your **Database Expert**, go to your **Current Connections** and **Add Command**.  Use this to write up a SQL query to save the usage data to a table in your data source  (If your data source is read only, just add a delimited text file as an additional data source and output your usage data to that instead.)

The best example I have of this is @ http://www.scribd.com/doc/2190438/20-Secrets-of-Crystal-Reports. On page 39, you'll see a method for creating a table of contents that more or less uses this method.

Comment: +1 Good answer and link. I had never tried this either and assumed it wouldn't work, but not sure why I assumed that. I want to point out that the article says that it is not recommended as something that should be done, but it's nice to know you can if necessary.